# Query param allowed values in emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using ember's query parameters to filter a results list by a type of layout. I'd like to check whether the specified query is in availableLayouts. I know I can check whether the value is in this array, but I'm not sure at what point ember sets the "layout" parameter. Is there a method or action that is called where I can override the set call to make sure it exists in availableLayouts?

```
queryParams: ['filter', 'layout']
layout: 'grid'
availableLayouts: ['grid', 'list']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a computed property to accomplish what you would like.

You can do something like

```
  queryParams: ['filter', 'layout'],
  layout: 'grid',
  availableLayouts: ['grid', 'list'],
  isLayoutAvailable: function(){
    var layout = this.get('layout');
    var availableLayouts = this.get('availableLayouts');
    return availableLayouts.contains(layout);
  }.property('layout', 'availableLayouts.[]')
```

that would create an `isLayoutAvailable` property which would automatically be updated if the layout is in the array of availableLayouts

you can see a working bin here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gaker/1/edit?html,js,output